# getting error message from server during API call

Tags: swift, generics, alamofire, rx-swift

I have an app where I used RxSwift for my networking by extending ObservableType this works well but the issue I am having now is when I make an API request and there is an error, I am unable to show the particular error message sent from the server. Now how can I get the particular error response sent from the server

```
extension ObservableType {

    func convert<T: EVObject>(to observableType: T.Type) -> Observable<T> where E: DataRequest {

        return self.flatMap({(request) -> Observable<T> in

            let disposable = Disposables.create {
                request.cancel()
            }

            return Observable<T>.create({observer -> Disposable in

                request.validate().responseObject { (response: DataResponse<T>) in
                                        switch response.result {
                    case .success(let value):

                        if !disposable.isDisposed {
                            observer.onNext(value)
                            observer.onCompleted()
                        }
                    case .failure(let error):

                        if !disposable.isDisposed {
                            observer.onError(NetworkingError(httpResponse: response.response,
                                                             networkData: response.data, baseError: error))
                            observer.onCompleted()
                        }

                    }
                }

                return disposable
            })

        })
    }

}

let networkRetryPredicate: RetryPredicate = { error in
    if let err = error as? NetworkingError, let response = err.httpResponse {
        let code = response.statusCode
        if code >= 400 && code < 600 {
            return false
        }
    }

    return true
}

// Use this struct to pass the response and data along with 
// the error as alamofire does not do this automatically
public struct NetworkingError: Error {
    let httpResponse: HTTPURLResponse?
    let networkData: Data?
    let baseError: Error
}
```

response from the server could be

```
{
  "status" : "error",
  "message" : " INSUFFICIENT_FUNDS"
}
```

or

```
{
  "status" : "success",
  "data" : " gghfgdgchf"
}
```

my response is handled like this

```
class MaxResponse<T: NSObject>: MaxResponseBase, EVGenericsKVC {
    var data: T?

    public func setGenericValue(_ value: AnyObject!, forUndefinedKey key: String) {
        switch key {
        case "data":
            data = value as? T
        default:
            print("---> setGenericValue '\(value)' forUndefinedKey '\(key)' should be handled.")
        }
    }

    public func getGenericType() -> NSObject {
        return T()
    }
}
```

the error is

```
return ApiClient.session.rx.request(urlRequest: MaxApiRouter.topupWall(userId: getUser()!.id!, data: body))
            .convert(to: MaxResponse<Wall>.self)
```

Comment: Where is your network request? Please add that part too.

Comment: done the request

Comment: It looks like you are using an imported library and not the native networking stack. Are you using Alamofire?

Comment: yes I am using Alamofire

Comment: Okay, this is an Alamofire issue so I updated the tags for you.

Comment: Thanks, I add a bounty to the question

Comment: try removing the `validate()` method from the request. If we add `validate()` and if there is an error ie., the alamofire will directly return alamofire unacceptable status code error. If this is not your case Please specify the error you are getting. validate() method validate status code from 200-300 as success and rest as an error.

Comment: @FebinFathah validate is an Alamofire function

Comment: Yes, It will validates the status code

Comment: For error the status code will not be pass the alamofire validation and it will return only an NSError model. Please try it without validate. If you can access the error response from server we can fix this accordingly

Comment: when I remove `validate`, nothing gets shown in the failure block, but when I added `validate()`, it prints `responseValidationFailed(reason: Alamofire.AFError.ResponseValidationFailureReason.unacceptableStatusCode(code: 404))` and every other error code

Answer (score 0):

In the [official Alamofire docs](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Usage.md#automatic-validation) it is mentioned that `validate()`, **without any parameters**:

> Automatically validates status code within 200..<300 range, and that
>   the Content-Type header of the response matches the Accept header of
>   the request, if one is provided.

So if you do not include Alamofire's `validate()` you are saying that no matter the status code, if the request did get through, you will consider it successful, so that's why it shows nothing in the failure block.

However if you prefer to use it, yes, it will give you an `ResponseValidationFailureReason` error, but you still have access to the `response.data`. Try printing it, you should see the expected error response from the server:

```
if let responseData = response.data {
    print(String(data: responseData, encoding: .utf8))
}
```